# Gtk signal with multiple arguments

Tags: c, gtk, signals

### Context

After writing a simple application using a `GtkEntry` widget to process textual commands from user I would like to do some design changes.

As of now I use signal hook on key-press. If key(s) are a specified value, then show command line and process various actions on `entry` widget. Like e.g.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>: move cursor to start of input.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>: delete text before the cursor.
- ...

As well as parsing commands and saving/loading history.

I am not satisfied with how this is stitched together. The command parsing becomes a subset of:

```
main_window -> mode_check -> command_line_act -> parse_cmd+execute
```

As I see it one good approach would be to write a new widget using GtkEntry as base – and send signals on *command enter*. All of the internals like Ctrl+... and history handled by the new widget.

Signals emitted from new widget being e.g.:

- "cmdline-abort"
- "cmdline-cmd"
- ...

### Status

Have written the base for this but I am at a hault when it comes to emitting signals with more then one argument.

I have:

```
gtk_signal_emit(obj, sig, 0, command)
                                 |
                                 +---- string.
```

but would like, (for now at least, most likely more/other down the line.):

```
gtk_signal_emit(obj, sig, 0, command, length)
```

<sup>*gtk_emit_signal* Typo fixed. [Thanks to jku.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940119/2148245). Also, now using *g_signal_*</sup>

---

In widget code:

```
static void
cmdline_class_init(CmdlineClass *klass)
{
```

With one argument I am using [g_signal_new()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/2.28/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-new) as:

```
cmdline_signals[CMDLINE_CMD] = g_signal_new(
                "cmdline-cmd",
                G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS(klass),
                G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST | G_SIGNAL_ACTION,
                G_STRUCT_OFFSET(CmdlineClass, cmdline),
                NULL,
                NULL,
                g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__VOID,
                G_TYPE_NONE,
                1,
                G_TYPE_STRING
);
```

And as I see it, for two arguments, should change it to something like:

```
cmdline_signals[CMDLINE_CMD] = g_signal_new(
                "cmdline-cmd",
                G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS(klass),
                G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST | G_SIGNAL_ACTION,
                G_STRUCT_OFFSET(CmdlineClass, cmdline),
                NULL,
                NULL,
                g_cclosure_user_marshal_VOID__STRING_INT,
                G_TYPE_NONE,
                2,
                G_TYPE_STRING,
                G_TYPE_INT
);
```

---

### Trouble in the garden

Using [glib-genmarshal](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/glib-genmarshal.html) to generate marshals with marshal.list holding:

```
VOID:STRING,INT
```

This works, but gives me a warning upon compile time as:

```
warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type
```

Caused by this code generated by glib-genmarshal:

```
  typedef void (*GMarshalFunc_VOID__STRING_INT) (gpointer     data1,
                                                 gpointer     arg_1,
                                                 gint         arg_2,
                                                 gpointer     data2);

  register GMarshalFunc_VOID__STRING_INT callback;

  /* GCC Warnig: conversion of object pointer to function => */
  callback = (GMarshalFunc_VOID__STRING_INT) ( 
                    marshal_data ? 
                    marshal_data : 
                    cc->callback
  );
```

---

### Question

Is this the wrong approach? Is there some way to fix the conversion error? Etc.

*As a note: I am fairly new to Gtk, and Gui programming in general.*

---

#### Side point

There are some deprecations I also wonder if could affect the code / should be avoided:

- [GtkSignalMarshaller](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Types.html#GtkSignalMarshaller), does this indicate anything about the status of `GSignalCMarshaller`?
- [GtkCallbackMarshal](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Types.html#GtkCallbackMarshal), does this indicate anything about the use of marshalers in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning does appear (with -pedantic) on some signal marshalling code, and not just in your code. As far as I can see you are not doing anything wrong though -- except for using `gtk_signal_emit()` (I assume you meant that and not gtk_emit_signal() which does not exist as far as I know): you should not use any gtk_signal-prefixed code: that stuff is  all deprecated. See the [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Signals.html#gtk-signal-emit) for details. Use [GObject](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-emit) instead: `g_signal_emit()` or `g_signal_emit_by_name()` should work for you.

The signal marshaller deprecations you mention are about this same thing: GObject handles everything related to this now (and has for a long time already).

As practical advice: Often adding things to signal signatures is not worth the trouble, and this might be the case for you as well: maybe your signal does not need the command string at all, and the signal handler could just query it with your_object_get_command()?

Practical advice #2: Consider using GTK+ 3 for new code. Not having all that deprecated stuff around confusing everyone is just lovely.

Comment: Thanks – long gone, but here I am. Yes, I get that it is an issue for other code as well, I was wondering if there was a way to *fix it by modifying the generated code* or use another similar method. However– I rewrote huge parts of the code and seems to have missed (and misused) some of the normal chains of signal communication. I still have a lot to grasp. As for GTK2/3 I have used code that compile with both, as in `#if GTK_CHECK_VERSION(3,0,0)` use one else the other. Perhaps more hassle then convenience. And yes, that *emit()* was a typo. Luckily it was the only `gtk_` signal-code used.

Comment: In new code I discarded using my own marshaling code and used the *bundled* ones, e.g. `g_cclosure_marshal_VOID__STRING`. (But guess in reality the issue might remain, only difference being the warning is *hidden* as in *pushed down the chain to compilation of native glib* and not in my code).

Comment: Unless you always compile and test both GTK 2/3 code paths,  I don't think it's worth the trouble: the non-tested path will usually be broken,  and it makes the real code path more complex as well. An example of this was your signal emission code: that would not compile on GTK+ 3.

Comment: Yes, I always compile with both (as in compile very often with one, and include the other after changes that can affect compability). (It's a rather small project for now). And I started doing that after this post. Beside the ones I always use Wall, Wextra and pedantic I added `-DGDK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED`.